# How to get checked state of Checked Listbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, checkedlistbox

I have a checked listbox which I am running through and saving names to a database. As I run through I need to see if the check box is checked or clear.
I've tried the following code but to no avail:

```
If chklbRegister.GetItemCheckState(nLoop).ToString = "1" Then
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlAttended", 1)
Else
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlAttended", 0)
End If
```

I have also tried:

```
If chklbRegister.GetItemCheckState(nLoop) = True Then
```

but it still doesn't worked. Ideas please.
Thanks
Graham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetItemCheckState returns an Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkstate(v=vs.110).aspx). An enum is not a string and not a boolean.
You should test again the defined values of the enum

```
If chklbRegister.GetItemCheckState(nLoop) = CheckState.Checked Then
    -----
```

If you apply the ToString method to an enum value you get the translated text of the enum, in your case the word "Checked"  and not the string "1".
Of course, being the enums fundamentally numeric values of integral type you could always cast the return value to an integer, but you never should do it and use instead the proper Enum syntax

As a final note. This problem should have been signaled by the compiler and not slipped past the compilation phase. This compiler behavior is caused by the [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) set to Off instead of On. I suggest to change this option in the configuration of your project to avoid other errors of this kind that could be very subtle.

Comment: Thanks for that works a treat. I set Option Strict on and got 2069 Errors, something for me to sort out over the Christmas Break! Should I also turn on Option Explicit, which is something I used to specify in VB6?

Comment: Well that should be expected if you have a large program ported from VB6. For the Option Explicit On, I coud only say what is written on MSDN _Setting Option Explicit to Off is generally not a good practice. You could misspell a variable name in one or more locations, which would cause unexpected results when the program is run_

Comment: `Explicit On`, `Strict On` - *always* (there are a few exceptions where you need Option Strict Off for example late binding)

Answer (score 0):

You can see for the documentation for [GetItemCheckState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemcheckstate(v=vs.110).aspx) that it returns a value from the [CheckState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkstate(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration so you need to check this:

```
chklbRegister.GetItemCheckState(nLoop) = CheckState.Checked
```